# Add 1 to variable in Flask HTMl

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm using a for loop to change a variable's value. +1 each time the for loop goes
This is my HTML code:

```
{% set count = 1 %}
        {% for i in form %}
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="test" value="{{ i['Name'] }}">
                <div class="grid-item">{{ i["Name"] }}</div>
                {{ count }}
            </label>
            {% set count = count + 1 %}
        {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that count always stays 1. If I put the `{% set count = count + 1 %}` before the `{{ count }}` then count is always equal to 2.

I tested it in python and there it works,

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Comment: You were supposed to replace count with loop.index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [the `loop.index` counter variable](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for-loop).

```
{% for i in form %}
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="{{ i.Name }}">
        <div class="grid-item">{{ i.Name }}</div>
        {{ loop.index }}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```